# Bundle not found in iOS Framework

Tags: swift, frameworks, cocoapods, xib, nsbundle

At the moment I am working on a framework I want to use in different projects. This framework contains a couple of swift classes as well as resources like XIBs and images. Further I am using CocoaPods for the integration in other projects.

To handle all my resources I tried two different approaches. First the easy one by creating a resource-bundle using [resource_bundles with CocoaPods](http://www.the-nerd.be/2015/08/07/load-assets-from-bundle-resources-in-cocoapods/). It look good in the beginning, all my XIB files and images appeared in "Resources" folder of "Development Pods", however as soon as I tried to use them the app crashed because they could't be found in the bundle. Debugging the NSBundle.mainBundle() shows the ResourceBundle.bundle was not loaded, even if it appeared in the "Products" folder.

In my second approach I created a Bundle-target in my framework and copied all the resources into this bundle. I attached the created bundle by using CocoaPods resource_bundle again.

`s.resource_bundle = { 'ResourceBundle' => [ '.MyProjectBundle.bundle'] }`

The Bundle was attached and appeared in the "Resources" directory of "Development Pods", but again my XIBs couldn't be loaded, neither could I find my MyProjectBundle.bundle in NSBundle.mainBundle()

[image: Framework and Bundle]

I hope someone can help me with this issue.

cheers,
Chris

Comment: does no one else have had this problem?